# How to set time out to this?

Tags: javascript, time, set, out

I want it to automatically press the ok button after the window is opened for 20 seconds.
I don't know how exactly to do this.
code is:

```
window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function() {
    if (this.isOpen() && this.active) {

        if (Input.isRepeated('ok')) { 
            this.processOk();
        }
    }
};
```

What I tried:

```
window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function() {
    if (this.isOpen() && this.active) {

       { setTimeout(function ()   if (Input.isRepeated('ok')) { 
            this.processOk();
        } , 20000); }

    }
};
```

Edit:

I actually decided to use this code below. I want to call ok handler after window has been opened for 20 seconds.

```
Window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function() {
    if (this.isOpen() && this.active) {

   setTimeout(function(){

    this.callOkHandler();

},2000);



    }
};
```

But I got uncaught type error this.callokhandler is not a function

Any help is appreciated Thanks in advance

Comment: simple typo in your setTimeout() callback.

Comment: I have edited the question, I decided to use a different code, I got uncaught type error this.callokhandler is not a function, do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You've misplaced your `if()` condition before the function `{`.

Try:

```
window_NameInput.prototype.processHandling = function(){
  if (this.isOpen() && this.active) { 
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (Input.isRepeated('ok')) {
          this.processOk();
        }
      }, 20000);
  }
};
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have edited the question, I decided to use a different code, but I got uncaught type error this.callokhandler is not a function, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: We have to see your `callOkHandler` function. PS, this should be added as a new question not appended to your previous question.

Comment: I am new to javascript, this is the full code https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpbzclydv5sf1fn/rpg_windows.js?dl=0